# React pass ref to adjacent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I would like to access the position of one SVG element, to draw another SVG element in React. Therefore I would like to use `getBoundingClientRect()` and need to access the DOM of the first SVG element from the adjacent SVG element.

**EDIT:**
Example: I have a `circle` and would like to draw a `rect` on top of it.

I can access the circles ref after the `OtherSVGELement` did mount. But I can't access the neighbouring `circle` elements ref when rendering the `rect`

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.firstRef = React.createRef();
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <svg>
                <circle ref={this.firstRef} />
                <OtherSVGElement circleRef={this.firstRef}/>
            </svg>
        )
    };
};

class OtherSVGElement extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log(this.props.circleRef.current);
    };


    render() {
       return (
           <svg>
               /* Doesn't work; current is null */
               <rect x=this.props.circleRef.current.x /> 
           </svg>
       )
    };
};
```

How can I overcome this problem? In my case the circles position is way harder to obtain. That's why I wanted to use `getBoundingClientRect()`.

Comment: `ref` is only created when component mounted to the dom. `render` is executed before component mounted. That's why you get `null` when `console.log(props.otherRef)` in `constructor`. You can try `log` `ref` in `componentDidMount` instead`

Comment: Yes, I figured that out now. But how can I than access the element in a neighbouring element. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your instincts are correct. You'll be able to access the ref in other lifecycle hooks, such as `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  console.log(this.props.otherRef);
}
```

By the way, you're probably looking for the `current` attribute on the ref (`this.props.otherRef.current`), which will be the reference to the DOM node.

Comment: That worked. Unfortunately, now I can't access the ref in the render function of the second component. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Can you update your question/code with an example of the new issue?

Comment: I suspect in this case you can use a short-circuit evaluation to make sure what you're looking for exists: `<rect x={this.props.circleRef && this.props.circleRef.current.x} />`. That being said, why do the elements have to be uncontrolled rather than react maintaining the position statefully?

Comment: I am creating an SVG and use nested group tags (<g>). The circles are positioned relative to their parent group. The groups position is determined using `transform` and `translate`. Therefore I don't have the absolute position of the circles.